# Power automate - how to provide business user information?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Let`s say that I prepared simple approvals process. How to provide to business user status of flow?

Of course we can use power automate and show logs or we can update item column with data "document send to Adam" but is there any easier solution to show processing of current flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

As a workaround, you can add a hyperlink column in library or list, then update the column with flow run history for each item.

Ways to get the flow URL and update column:

[image]

Compose: `workflow()`

Compose2:

```
concat('https://unitedkingdom.flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/',outputs('Compose')['tags']['environmentName'],'/flows/',outputs('Compose')['name'],'/runs/',outputs('Compose')['run']['name'])
```

Result:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://sharepains.com/2018/06/25/microsoft-flow-which-flow-ran-on-my-sharepoint-list-item-or-document-part-2/